# Angular NG-Select Theme SCSS imports not working and showing the @Import as Unknown Property Name

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material, angular-ngselect

I'm having issues using a scss import. I am trying to import both the default styles and material styles from the NG Select library. This was working before but I think broke during the upgrade to angular 14.

```
.ng-select-material {
  @import "~@ng-select/ng-select/themes/material.theme.css";
}

.ng-select-default {
  @import "~@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css";
}
```

This is really all there is to the code, and depending on which theme was needed for the input it would use one of these classes, but now neither styles are applying and in the browser inspect for either of those classes the import is striked out and says "Unknown Property Name".

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

If anyone runs into a similar problem, changing the path to "node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/material.theme" fixed it for me.

```
.ng-select-material {
  @import "node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/material.theme";
}

.ng-select-default {
  @import "node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme";
}
```

Comment: I'm struggling with this as well. What does your `ng-select` call look like? Is it literally `<ng-select class="ng-select-material"></ng-select>`?

Comment: In my project that ng-select-material class is on a parent div around the ng-select. Although at the time of posting this it was working, recently it seems that the styles have started doing some weird stuff again.


`
<div class="ng-select-material">
<ng-select></ng-select>
</div>
`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for giving me the hint!
On Angular 15 this one worked for me:

```
@import "../node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css";
```